# What's up with gcc's handling of alloca?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, alloca

On most platforms, `alloca` just boils down to an inline adjustment of the stack pointer (for example, subtracting from `rsp` on x64, plus a bit of logic to maintain stack alignment).

I was looking at the code that `gcc` generates for alloca and it is pretty weird. Take the following simple example<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stddef.h>

volatile void *psink;

void func(size_t x) {
  psink = alloca(x);
}
```

This compiles to the following assembly at `-O2`:

```
func(unsigned long):
        push    rbp
        add     rdi, 30
        and     rdi, -16
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, rdi
        lea     rax, [rsp+15]
        and     rax, -16
        mov     QWORD PTR psink[rip], rax
        leave
        ret
```

There are several confusing things here. I understand that `gcc` needs to round the allocated size up to a multiple of 16 (to maintain stack alignment), and the usual way to do that would be `(size + 15) & ~0xF` but instead it adds 30 at `add     rdi, 30`? What's up with that?

Second, I would just expect the result of `alloca` to be the new `rsp` value, which is already well-aligned. Instead, gcc does this:

```
    lea     rax, [rsp+15]
    and     rax, -16
```

Which seems to be "realigning" the value of `rsp` to use as the result of `alloca` - but we already did the work to align `rsp` to a 16-byte boundary in the first place.

What's up with that?

You can play with the code [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/USKS2M). It is worth noting that `clang` and `icc` do the "expected thing" on x86 at least. With VLAs (as suggested in earlier comments), `gcc` and `clang` does fine while `icc` produces an abomination.

---

1 Here, the assignment to `psink` is just to consume the result of `alloca` since otherwise the compiler just omits it entirely.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136822/discussion-on-question-by-beeonrope-whats-up-with-gccs-handling-of-alloca).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very old, normal priority [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50938). The code works correctly. It's just that when the size is larger than 1 byte, 16 more bytes are unnecessarily allocated. So it's not a correctness bug, it's a minor efficiency bug.