# What is the point of __builtin_alloca

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am reading a code where someone calls

```
__builtin_alloca(n)
```

I read the GCC documentation and it says that it is allocating an object of size n in the stack.

How is this different from just declaring an array?

Comment: I think the manual is clear on this one - `For
       certain applications, its use can improve efficiency compared to the
       use of malloc(3) plus free(3).  In certain cases, it can also
       simplify memory deallocation in applications that use longjmp(3) or
       siglongjmp(3).  Otherwise, its use is discouraged`

Comment: `alloca` style stack based memory allocation predates the VLA feature. So, now there's not too much difference between the two.  You have to be careful in either case when n is a very large number.

Comment: Also it's worth noting while you are not allowed to use goto to jump over variable sized arrays, alloca actually allows you to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of alloca](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Advantages-of-Alloca.html), [Why is the use of alloca() not considered good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1018853/608639), [Alloca implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/714692/608639), [What's up with gcc's handling of alloca?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42496286/608639), etc.

Comment: There are ways in which using `alloca()` (or it's underlying implementation, `__builtin_alloca()`) is analogous to using a VLA (variable length array).  However, IIRC, there are also differences, most notably if you use `alloca()` in a loop (roughly: don't!).